# all the columns and labels in y axis stack together in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text, geom-col

I am trying to visualize with ggplot2 in R, with geom_col and geom_text.
My problem is that, before I make data labels with geom_text, my visualization is shown properly, as in the following codes and visualizaiton

```
ggplot(data=highest_lost_products_sales)+
  geom_col(mapping=aes(reorder(productid,-total_profit), y=total_profit),
           fill="seagreen")+
  labs(title = "Highest Lost Products",x="Product IDs",y="Lost profits")
```

[image]

However, when I add the "geom_text" part, the visualization becomes like this"

```
ggplot(data=highest_lost_products_sales)+
  geom_col(mapping=aes(reorder(productid,-total_profit), y=total_profit),
           fill="seagreen")+
  labs(title = "Highest Lost Products",x="Product IDs",y="Lost profits")+
  geom_text(aes(label=scales::comma(total_profit,accurary=1),
                x=productid, y=total_profit))
```

[image]

I would like to know what happened and how to solve this

Comment: Try with `x = reorder(productid,-total_profit)` in geom_text too. My guess is that `productid` is a numeric. Using `reorder` you convert it to a factor in geom_col but in geom_text the values are treated as numbers.